# javascript to replace element value with empty space

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to replace the a tspan which contains $ symbol with empty tspan probably a space. Is there a way to replace it in the entire project on load of the page?

Comment: As of this comment, your question isn't very clear. Additionally, your example isn't showing up. Would you mind providing more details with exactly what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think I probably got the answer below. I need to try it. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the original version of your question was what you meant (to display HTML, you need to enclose them in back quotes, e.g. `<tspan>`):

To replace every `<tspan class="symbol">$</tspan>` with `<tspan> </tspan>`, this is one way to do it:

```
$(
    $('tspan.symbol').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == '$') {
            $(this).removeClass('symbol');
            $(this).text(' ');
        }
    });
);
```

Comment: Does it makes effect on page load directly?